# Python - Create a column based on multiple other columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column that outputs ascending or descending depending on values in other columns

```
  Index Leg  Map Number
   0     AD  J1   1
   1     AD  J1   2
   2     AD  J1   3
   3     AD  J2   5
   4     AD  J2   3
   4     AF  J1   9
   5     AF  J1   6
```

So looking at this dataframe, I want to create a new column "updown" that is either ascending or descending depending based on the leg, map and number columns. Basically for every leg and map pairings, look at the number column in order to determine whether the numbers are ascending or descending....which will result in a dataframe like:

```
  Index Leg  Map Number Updown
   0     AD  J1   1     ascending
   1     AD  J1   2     ascending
   2     AD  J1   3     ascending
   3     AD  J2   5     descending
   4     AD  J2   3     descending
   4     AF  J1   9     descending
   5     AF  J1   6     descending
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `"For each leg, if the map is the same, look at the number column to determine the order..."` How? What is the logic?

Comment: It is not clear to me how the input maps on the output. You probably should explain for the sample data here why you used `ascending`/`descending`.

Comment: I have corrected this @harvpan

Comment: How do you determine for the first occurrence of the pairing?

Comment: @harvpan you determine by looking at each pairing in full not just the first occurrence

Comment: Will the numbers always be monotonically increasing / decreasing per leg?

Comment: @user3483203 yes they will always be monotonically increasing / decreasing per leg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need:

```
s=df.groupby(['Leg','Map'])['Number'].transform(lambda x: (x.diff()>0).any())
```

Or:

```
s=df.groupby(['Leg','Map'])['Number'].transform(lambda x: x.is_monotonic) #thanks Mark Wang
df['Updown']=np.where(s,'ascending','descending')
print(df)
```

---

```
   Index Leg Map  Number      Updown
0      0  AD  J1       1   ascending
1      1  AD  J1       2   ascending
2      2  AD  J1       3   ascending
3      3  AD  J2       5  descending
4      4  AD  J2       3  descending
5      4  AF  J1       9  descending
6      5  AF  J1       6  descending
```

Comment: Just a quick comment, there's actually a `is_monotonic_increasing` method with groupby